# Ionic 4 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(http://localhost/)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular7

I'm facing a problem that when I try to create mobile Front-End application based on Ionic 4 but a net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(http://localhost/) show up when I run it with cordova on android studio emulator.
This what i m using

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Ionic version   4.5.0
```

My config.xml

[image: config.xml]

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and replace the image of config.xml with the text from that file and then format it in the editor using the format as code button? Images of text are not accessible, nor are they searchable.

Answer (score 9):

> You can try to use this

```
ionic capacitor run <platform> [options]

ionic capacitor run android -l --external
```

> **--external** can help to use the app on external devices on the same
> network. just try it...

```
ionic capacitor run
ionic capacitor run android
ionic capacitor run android -l
ionic capacitor run ios --livereload
ionic capacitor run ios --livereload-url=http://localhost:8100
```

> I found this on capacitor docs [ionic capacitor run](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/capacitor-run)

Comment: It worked the first time without --external flag. Kind of weird but now this fix works.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else losing their mind that might be using Capacitor go into your `capacitor.config.json` file and remove this:

```
"server": {
    "url": "http://localhost:8100"
}
```

I've had this in my config file for sometime and only just now started causing issues so I'm not sure if a new Capacitor patch has changed this behavior on prod builds or what but this resolved my issue. God speed to the rest of you.

Comment: Man, you are savior! I've been banging my head since two days on this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

**20-09-2020:** For **Capacitor** apps

This didn't work for me: I don't know why.

```
ionic cap run android -l --external
```

But this works:

```
ionic cap run android -l --host=0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this versions:

```
"@capacitor/android": "^2.4.3",
"@capacitor/cli": "^2.4.3",
"@capacitor/core": "^2.4.3"
```

And im changed capacitor.config.json file:

Add this:

```
"server": {
    "cleartext": true
  }
```

And turn false `"bundledWebRuntime"`

And it worked!