# Ionic 5/Capacitor ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED in Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

I'm using **Capacitor** for building the Ionic app. These are the following commands run in order to open the android app in Android Studio.

```
npx cap add android
ionic build
npx cap copy
npx cap open android
```

In Android Studio, I ran the build and click on Run after which I see the error `net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED` in my device. I have seen various posts having the same error but those are with `Cordova` build. In my case, I'm not using Cordova for preparing the android app.

[image: error-message]

Here are few excerpts from my Ionic App.

`capacitor.config.json`file

```
{
  "appId": "com.abc",
  "appName": "abc",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "cordova": {
    "preferences": {
      "ScrollEnabled": "false",
      "android-minSdkVersion": "19",
      "BackupWebStorage": "none",
      "SplashMaintainAspectRatio": "true",
      "FadeSplashScreenDuration": "0",
      "SplashShowOnlyFirstTime": "false",
      "SplashScreen": "none",
      "SplashScreenDelay": "0"
    }
  },
  "server": {
    "url": "http://192.168.1.208:8100"
  }
}
```

I also see this error in LogCat of Android Studio

```
W/cr_AwContents: Application attempted to call on a destroyed WebView
    java.lang.Throwable
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.a(PG:127)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.a(PG:209)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.evaluateJavaScript(PG:8)
        at android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript(WebView.java:1113)
        at com.getcapacitor.cordova.MockCordovaWebViewImpl$1.run(MockCordovaWebViewImpl.java:203)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58705937/7004388) helped me find the solution to my problem.

I removed the field `server` in the **capacitor.config.json** file to make it work.

```
"server": {
    "url": "http://localhost:8100"
}
```

Now my **capacitor.config.json** looks like

```
{
  "appId": "com.abc",
  "appName": "abc",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "cordova": {
    "preferences": {
      "ScrollEnabled": "false",
      "android-minSdkVersion": "19",
      "BackupWebStorage": "none",
      "SplashMaintainAspectRatio": "true",
      "FadeSplashScreenDuration": "0",
      "SplashShowOnlyFirstTime": "false",
      "SplashScreen": "none",
      "SplashScreenDelay": "0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: all that did was turn off live reload, and that is why your app started working

Comment: I did not use livereload at all for my app to run. Somehow, that `server` line got added in the `capacitor.config.json` file and when i removed that field, my app started working in the device and emulator both. I did not have to use any of `android:usesCleartextTraffic` attributes in the manifest.xml

Comment: @coderpc is right. happend for me to. From one second to another without changes by myself this line got added too and nothing worked anymore. Removed it and everything works normal now. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Add this to you `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `application` element

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Once I added this statement, it gave `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error in the device.

Comment: I think this is the correct way if doing it, because it fits with capacitor's philosophy of _Code once, configure everywhere_

Comment: I was told to come here and find the solution for my issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602933/ionic-login-button-not-working-on-android-emulator) but it didn't help me either.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to only enable this for local development cases?

Answer (score 12):

When you specify the `server` in your Capacitor config, you should set `server.cleartext` to `true` to prevent this issue from happening. Example:

```
{
  "appId": "com.abc",
  "appName": "abc",
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "server": {
    "url": "http://192.168.1.208:8100", 
    "cleartext": true
  }
}
```

From the [config documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config):

```js
    /**
     * Allow cleartext traffic in the Web View.
     *
     * On Android, all cleartext traffic is disabled by default as of API 28.
     *
     * This is intended for use with live-reload servers where unencrypted HTTP
     * traffic is often used.
     *
     * **This is not intended for use in production.**
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     * @default false
     */
```

Comment: didn't help! now it takes a long time with a white screen and then it throws `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: I don't understand how this could help, and this definitely did not fix the problem for me.  The ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED message looks like it is coming from the WebView client.  This solution only seems to add cleartext support to the internal server.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @deltamind106 From the [config documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config) (which I believe did not exist when this answer was written initially), it seems like this boolean should configure the WebView client in a way that it allows cleartext communication.

Answer (score 12):

You can allow `cleartext` traffic in the Web View by enabling it on the **capacitor.config** file, by adding the below code

```
server: {
  cleartext: true
}
```

Build your project to see the changes

```
ionic capacitor build android
```

Comment: Show show, Thank You

Answer (score 5):

Add this code into capacitor.config:
server: {
cleartext: true
}

Comment: Show show, Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Go into `capacitor.config.json` and add the `cleartext: true` prop:

```json
"server": {
  "cleartext": true
}
```

then, run `npx cap copy`, start the server, re-compile and run the project from your IDE (Xcode/AndroidStudio) again.

Answer (score 1):

just run this command :

```
ionic capacitor run android -l --ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

While solutions above might work, it is also worth checking if your web assets were correctly copied to the `android/app/src/main` directory as the same `net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED` error will be raised due to missing index.html.

In some cases, e.g. when `cap sync` cannot delete the previous assets directory, files are not copied correctly, but process does not exit with error.

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:
https://www.basezap.com/fix-leartext-error-for-websites/

In app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml edit application tag adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" property

Answer (score 0):

Create a file under android>src>main>res>xml>network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <network-security-config>
     <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
     <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.208</domain>
     </domain-config>
  </network-security-config>
```

then in your AndroidManifest.xml inside application tag add

android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  After further testing, in particular the solution to my problem was to upgrade the @capacitor/android and @capacitor/core packages both to 4.6.2.  If you have a version of these packages that is 4.6.1 or earlier, then the problem occurs.

After trying all the other answers here and elsewhere, all to no avail, the solution for me was to upgrade the entire project (including my custom Capacitor plugins) to use Capacitor 4.x.  Depending on your project, this may be easier said than done.  If you can use the built-in upgrade tools then great, but of course they failed for me and I had to upgrade manually.

It is not clear exactly why my Capacitor 3.x project suddenly started getting this error, but upgrading to 4.x solved the problem.  This is probably not the first solution you should try, but if all else fails, it's something to try and it can't hurt to be on the latest version of Capacitor.