# Ionic NOT getting response from API

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, get

I'm actually building an app with the use of IONIC framework. I'm trying to get back some value from API which is working find on the web view of the ionic (ionic serve) but when i run the command *ionic capacitor run android* it does not work on the android version and its giving back the following error:

```
{"headers": {"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate": null, "headers":{}},"status": 0, "statusText": "Unknown Error", "url": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/company","ok":"false","name":"HttpErrorResponse","message" : "Http failure response for http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/company: 0 Unknown Error","error": {"isTrusted":true}}listing
```

this is the code from the http.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class HttpService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/company";

  getCompany() {
    return this.http.get(this.URL).toPromise();
  }
}
```

and this is the code from home.page.ts:

```
import { HttpService } from "../services/http.service";

    this.http
      .getCompany()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.companies_array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));

        this.is_loading = false;
      })
      .catch((response) => {
        this.err_msg = JSON.stringify(response);
      });
```

i've added the import in app.module.ts:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
```

And i've added a file call proxy.conf.json where i've added the following code:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

and i've modify the angular.json file where :

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
```

Comment: Check This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907425/5909026

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic 5/Capacitor ERR\_CLEARTEXT\_NOT\_PERMITTED in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60906953/ionic-5-capacitor-err-cleartext-not-permitted-in-android)

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib in a way you help me to find the solution. 
`
  "server": {
    "cleartext": true
  }
`
this was the answer
Everybody here is thanking you. God bless you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same issue, you can you fix something like that. You have to just add one line, i.e.

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

in your manifest file i.e.,

[yourProject]/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml