# ionic 5 Ionic/Angular cannot make http request in android emulator(net: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: ionic-framework

I have already enabled cors in my rest API. I can succesfully make a request in my  browser, but when i run my application in android studio using this command "ionic cap run android --livereload --external", i cannot get any response from my api. when checking the console i got below error  "net: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCbKT.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic 5/Capacitor ERR\_CLEARTEXT\_NOT\_PERMITTED in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60906953/ionic-5-capacitor-err-cleartext-not-permitted-in-android)

Comment: i have already done this, still cannot make a requeset

Comment: What Errors are coming?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib bro this is also my problem i cannot log any error in android studio, so im blindly solving this issue. i have tried using remote debugging in chrome, but i cannot see my device

Comment: Have you enabled Developer option in your mobile device?

Comment: yes i have, also i choose allow file transfer

Comment: do you have ADB installed? try command `adb devices` to see connected devices on on terminal or CMD.

Comment: i have installed ADB and was able to see the error now upon checking the dev tools, i see this error: "net: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED", also i have check in my api and there is no requests that went through, do you have any idea on what wizardy is going on around here!!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test your app on Android Studio and your API is running on localhost, you need to send requests to **10.0.2.2** instead of localhost. In your case, instead of using the base API URL http://localhost:3000 in your Ionic app, use http://10.0.2.2:3000.

Next, add `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to the application element in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
<application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

You will need your **IPv4 Address**. Open Command Prompt, enter `ipconfig` and take note of the IPv4 Address.

Create a file named **network_security_config.xml** in the path *android\app\src\main\res\xml* and replace ipv4address with your IPv4 Address:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">ipv4address</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Finally, run your app with the following command:

```
ionic cap run android -l --host=0.0.0.0
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `android:usecleartexttraffic` attributes in the config.xml.

```
<platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
...
</platform>
```

Also, you have to add subDomains of RestAPI in network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Greetings i have added above configuration still got the "net: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED",

Comment: May I see your added xml file?
Have you tried to run it via Android SDK?