# Ionic App connects with liveserver but not with localhost

Tags: asp.net, android-studio, ssl, ionic-framework, ssl-certificate

It works fine when I use the Browser with Ionic Serve but when I try to run it on my phone with android studio I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (when I use localhost, which makes sense) or anhttps://192.168.0.120:55275/umbraco/HbigApp/HbigAppSurface/GetBetriebeStartsWith net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR (when I use my laptops IP). The port is correct, the backend is up and running. I have cleared the caches on all my Browsers,  I have tried using my phones hotspot and I'm really not sure anymore what I could do.
My backend is in ASP.net, frontend is Ionic 5.

Frontend:

```
getUrl(action: string) {
    if (isDevMode()) {
      return (
        "https://192.168.0.120:55275/umbraco/HbigApp/HbigAppSurface/" + action
      );
    }
    return (
      "https://www.hierbinichgast.de/umbraco/HbigApp/HbigAppSurface/" + action
    );
}

  getBetriebe(): Observable<any> {
    const params = new HttpParams();

    return this.http.post<any>(this.helperService.getUrl("GetBetriebeStartsWith"),
    params,
    {headers: this.headers}
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you check by replacing Https to http like that:

http://192.168.0.120:55275/umbraco/HbigApp/HbigAppSurface/

and also i think your phone and source of application will be on same network

Comment: if I try to use http I get a CORS error

Comment: For CORS error have you already tried this one

Using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
 
To use Microsoft CORS package, you need to install from NuGet package.
 
Go to Tools Menu-> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console -> execute the below command.
 
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:5901/DemoApp/WebForm1.aspx", headers: "*", methods: "*")]  
public class ValuesController : ApiController  
{  
  
} 
```

Comment: Have you checked that the URL is accessible from other devices  ?

Comment: @DelwynPinto I have tried from my physical device and from an Android Studio emulator, both get the same error.

Comment: @Waleed I'll try

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic 5/Capacitor ERR\_CLEARTEXT\_NOT\_PERMITTED in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60906953/ionic-5-capacitor-err-cleartext-not-permitted-in-android)

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I tried ADDING a server url in the capacitor config since I didn't have one to begin with but that just made it that the app doesn't load at all