# Ionic/Capacitor net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when Android calling API

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an ionic vue app that I want to test as an android app.

I use following commands to create the app:

```
ionic cap add android
ionic build
ionic cap copy
ionic cap open android
```

Then I start the app on a virtual device in android studio. I use android API Level 30.

I get an `ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED` error when calling my django api (which I started locally, that's why there is no https).

I already tried adding this to my capacitor.config

```
server: {
  cleartext: true
}
```

This results in another error message: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I already tried various other things like suggested here: [Ionic 5/Capacitor ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60906953/ionic-5-capacitor-err-cleartext-not-permitted-in-android), but none helped so far.

When I use an Android version before API level 28 I get the `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` right away

Comment: when I change my axios baseURL from localhost to 10.0.2.2 it's working. But then of course the iOS and web app aren't working. Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by just adding a condition in my axios config:

```
const host = isPlatform('android') ? '10.0.2.2' : 'localhost'
```