# Ionic app doesn't hit on server when using capacitor

Tags: ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app, capacitor

My Ionic app works fine when running with ionic serve but when i use the command `ionic capacitor run android -l` it doesn't hit on sever and gives error

```
Webpage not available: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I am using the latest Ionic version.

**capacitor.config.json**

```json
{
  "appId": "fire.app.flashlight",
  "appName": "Flashlight",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "windowsAndroidStudioPath": "C:\\Users\\Digisoft\\Downloads\\Compressed\\android-studio-ide-201.6692364-windows\\android-studio\\bin\\studio64.exe",
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 0
    }
  },
  "cordova": {},
  "server": {
    "url": "http://localhost:8100",
    "cleartext": true
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure your device/emulator has access to the same WiFi network that your server is on. If you have multiple networks available when building, the Ionic CLI will let you choose which one to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic 4 net::ERR\_CONNECTION\_REFUSED(http://localhost/)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525558/ionic-4-neterr-connection-refusedhttp-localhost)

Answer (score 1):

Try to erase the "url" inside the "server"

Comment: Bravo sir, great answer, removing server key completely worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to reach localhost on emulator but not on remote host. Try to change url to wi-fi network of remote host 192.168.0.* something.